# Python convert webapp into desktop app or just show a webapp into a box like a desktop app

Tags: python

I'm a full stack web developer. I use python for web scraping and web automation. I was wondering that is it possible to convert a webapp into a desktop app or just a window which runs like browser and open a webapp into it.

Thanks in advance.